# How to override a non pluggable and non hookable function in a Wordpress parent theme?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, wordpress-theming, overriding

My parent theme has some bugs in a function I then want to override in my child theme.
The thing is it is neither pluggable and hookable. It is just defined like so :

```
// no if(!function_exists())
function parentThemeFunction() {
   //some bad coding
}
// no add_action
```

And that is all. It is not defined in functions.php either, but in "parentTheme/directory/file.php"

So i heard about "runkit_function_redefine" and "runkit_function_rename", but it means i have to implement "runkit" library on my server.

So far, my only option is to edit the original function in the parent theme. With the risk to see my code overrided at the very next theme update.

Any idea?

Comment: What if you just declare a new function and call it instead of 'parentThemeFunction' ?

Comment: You may have more help for that on the site for WordPress development questions : http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: @CarlosCarucce because i am not using it in my child theme. It is the parent theme that  is using it. Otherwise i will end up rewriting the  whole theme.

Comment: @mmm alright, thanks !